# Trouble displaying the data from an api

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

So, this a weird problem. Yesterday everything was working fine, I could see the category object displayed, I could switch between categories, but today I wanted to continue the project, but the data is not being displayed, I can not even see the object in the console. What could be the problem, is it in the Fetch  I would really really appreciate the help

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import URL from '../utilis/URL'
const BookContext = React.createContext();
export default function BooksProvider({ children }) {
  
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [currentSelectedCategory, setCurrentSelectedCategory] = useState([]);

  const handleSelectCategory = (category) => {
    setCurrentSelectedCategory(data[category]);
  };

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(URL);
    const result = await response.json();  
    console.log(data.result)
    setCurrentSelectedCategory(result[Object.keys(result)[0]]);
    setData(data);
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData();
  },[])
return (
    <BookContext.Provider value={{ data, handleSelectCategory, setCurrentSelectedCategory, currentSelectedCategory }}>
      {children}
    </BookContext.Provider>
  );
}
export {BookContext, BooksProvider}

import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import './Home.css'
import Books from './Books'
import { BookContext } from "../../context/books";
const Home = () => {
   const {data, handleSelectCategory, currentSelectedCategory } =React.useContext(BookContext)
    return (
        <div className='books__container' >
          <h1 className='categories'>Categories</h1>
            {Object.keys(data).map((key, index)=>{
            let books = data[key];
            return (
              <> 
              <span key={key} onClick={() => handleSelectCategory(key)} className='books__list' >
              {books[0].category}
              </span>         
             </>
              );})}
              <Books category={currentSelectedCategory} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't do anything:

```
console.log(data.result)
```

Because `data` is an empty array (and arrays have no `result` property anyway):

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
```

And this doesn't do anything:

```
setData(data);
```

Because you're just updating the state to *itself*, which changes nothing and probably doesn't trigger any re-render.  (Though even if it does, the render is mapping the elements of `data` which is still an empty array.)

You probably meant to set the `data` state object to the `result` from the API?:

```
setData(result);
```

Comment: It is working but, I don't get it, I have not touched the code and yesterday worked

Comment: @mura1: It's possible you've made a mistake.  They happen.  But if you really want to investigate then the first place you'd check is your source control history for that file.

Comment: Can't give you the right answer mark, bcs time